# Google API Geocoding using Bounds

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am running into some trouble using bounds with the Geocoding service provided by google.  My call is:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berea&bounds=41.45,-81.7|41.44,-81.6&key=`

I get one result, Berea KY.  This is confusing me greatly as I would expect to get Berea OH, as that is the lat/long range for Cleveland.

Could anyone explain to me how I should correct my search to get Berea, OH?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `bounds` were too tight.  This worked for me:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berea&bounds=41.35,-81.8|41.54,-81.5&key=
```

Comment: I believe you are correct, just missed the bounds.  Thank you very much!